# iOS today extension cannot find framework

Tags: ios, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios, today-extension, ios-extensions

I have added a Today Extension to my app. My app has multiple targets and uses pods, so I chose to embed the extension in one of the targets.

My app also uses Google Maps framework.

When I try to build the app (with the target, in which I embedded my extension), I get the "ld: framework not found Google Maps" issue, in my extension.

I don't want Google maps in my extension and neither added any google maps lib to my extension. Just adding a new extension target and building it, gives me this error.

Also, added the below flag in the pod file and did a pod install. But no luck !

```
target 'MyExtension' do
end
```

Here is the entire podfile

```
def available_pods
    pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet', '~> 1.8.1'
    pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 2.1.1'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'
end

target 'Pro' do
    available_pods
end

target 'Lite' do
    available_pods
end

target 'MyExtension' do
    available_pods
end
```

Comment: Show the entire pod.

Comment: @SachinVas edited my question and added the entire podfile. Please check.

Comment: In the above pod, you are trying to install GoogleMaps in available_pods and is inside MyExtension and your explanation contradicts it.